# Android RegExp first point

Tags: android, regex

i want to get description of image and substr for first point how to do this in android?

Example i have some text

> Text this is text, texxt. teeext wrwerwr bla bla

and hi give me a

> Text this is text, texxt.

how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know there is only one point in your description :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "Text this is text, texxt. teeext wrwerwr bla bla";
        String newstr="";

        if(null!=str && str.length() > 0 ){
             int endIndex = str.lastIndexOf(".");
            if(endIndex != -1)  {
                newstr = str.substring(0, endIndex); // not forgot to put check if( endIndex != -1)
        }
        }
        System.out.println(newstr);
    }
```

If there is multiple points :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "Text this is text, texxt. teeext wrwerwr bla bla";
        if(null!=str && str.length() > 0 ){
             String [] strings = str.split("\\.");
        System.out.println(strings[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can just use String.indexOf() and not String.lastIndexOf to make the first solution work for a sentence with multiple points as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regexp for this just look at this : [String.subSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence%28int,%20int%29)